# Neo4J community edition DB size limit?

Tags: neo4j, graph

The Neo4J site states that the community version of Neo4J has a limit in the graph size, but does not state the limit of the community version.

https://neo4j.com/editions/

What is the size limit of the community version?

Comment: I seem to remember that this spring, I read "limit is 100 million nodes" on the very page you are citing. Either they changed/removed it from the page or I don't recall it correctly

Answer (score 4):

I contacted uk@neo4j.com to ask for clarification and the answer they gave is that:

> There is a limit on node count and relationship count of 34Bn each

and

> The 34bn limit doesn't apply to Neo4j Enterprise

The [release announcement](https://neo4j.com/blog/neo4j-3-0-massive-scale-developer-productivity/) for 3.0 mentions a 34bn limit that no longer applies:

> Dynamic pointer compression expands Neo4j’s available address space as needed, making it possible to store graphs of any size. That’s right: no more 34 billion node limits!

So my guess is that 'Dynamic pointer compression' is an Enterprise Edition feature.

Answer (score -2):

From version 3.x.x there's not node limit for the graph.
For more reference you can go through this [reference](https://neo4j.com/blog/neo4j-3-0-massive-scale-developer-productivity/) saying

> Dynamic pointer compression expands Neo4j’s available address space as needed, making it possible to store graphs of any size. That’s right: no more 34 billion node limits!

currently we have billions of nodes in our servers with size upto TBs. It has been tested.

Hope this helps!

Comment: The linked page doesn't mention community edition at all.

Comment: I searched the page for 'community', 'edition', and 'limit' and found nothing about Community Edition. Please quote the relevant text in your answer (which would greatly improve your answer anyway).

Comment: it is ok now @JackDouglas. Hope this helps! :)

Comment: I saw that but it's referring to a previous limit in the enterprise edition, not community edition, as far as I can tell. There are a few references around to a CE limit of "100 million nodes", including the comment on the question by @tscherg